# Paypal instant update nvp not working (sandbox environment)

Tags: express, paypal, instant, nvp

I am currently implementing Paypal's express checkout using JAVA,  interfacing with the PayPal NVP API.  I have SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, DoExpressCheckout, DoAuthorization and DoCapture methods all working.  However, I need to implement the Instant Update API in order to calculate shipping costs and taxes on our server and display in paypal's page.  I followed all the steps and recommendations, however, the callback is never called.  I have tried playing with the setExpressCheckout parameters as I read in this forum that those parameters could be the problem but couldn't make it work yet. When I log in or change shipping addresses the callback is never called, I'm in sandbox environment BTW.

My callback url is public and works properly. When trying with a webbrowser it invokes my payPalCheckoutUpdate method and writes in a log file in my server, so I'm positive that the url was called. The problem is that when I log in paypal's checkout mobile site or change shipping address this callback url is never called.

My paypal update method is hosted in an Apache Ofbiz based application, I found in different forums that paypal can't access ofbiz's urls in port 8443 or 8080. So I used apache to redirect from my callback URL to my actual method and avoid using a port different than 80 in the callback url. (this works fine when tested with a webbrowser)

This is my call to setExpressCheckout without the credentials (let me know if you see a problem in this call)

**372623 [http-0.0.0.0-8443-3] INFO com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPAPICaller -
L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=0.00&CANCELURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdev2.XXXjacker.com%3A8443%2FXXXjacker%2Fcontrol%2FpayPalCheckoutCancel&MAXAMT=80.99&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=Calculated+Offline&AMT=80.99&RETURNURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdev2.XXXjacker.com%3A8443%2FXXXjacker%2Fcontrol%2FpayPalCheckoutReturn&CALLBACK=http%3A%2F%2Fdev2.XXXjacker.com%2FpayPalCheckoutUpdate&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_AMT0=80.99&TAXAMT=0.00&L_QTY0=1&L_NUMBER0=286202&SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&L_NAME0=DVD+%2B+VCR+w%2F+Line+in+%28no+tuner%29&ITEMAMT=80.99&CALLBACKVERSION+=84.0&VERSION=84.0&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Calculated+Offline&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=3&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PWD=******&SOURCE=PAYPAL_JAVA_SDK_76.0&SIGNATURE=**********&USER=xxxxx_12xxxx643_biz_api1.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com**

I tried with and without L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0 parameter, and also tried with version and callbackversion set to 76.0 (the default set by the java library I'm using, taken from paypal) I always get the same result, the callback url isn't invoked.

And this is the response from paypal:

**373536 [http-0.0.0.0-8443-3] INFO com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPAPICaller - TOKEN=EC%2dXXXXXXXX03911650G&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d06%2d12T22%3a03%3a06Z&CORRELATIONID=f1e3c64211d5e&ACK=Success&VERSION=84%2e0&BUILD=2975009 Ack : 200  Elapsed Time : 914 ms**

Thank you in advance for your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Callback may need to be SSL?:

- http://www.konakart.com/forum/index.php?topic=280.0
- http://afillyateit.com/forums/topic/500

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440586/paypal-not-redirecting-as-expected I am having same issue and switching to https doesn't help... Any word from author on what fixed it?